# calling script within script for redis command

Tags: redis

I have created several redis command scripts. eg AppendKeys, Client,Config, DELKey .I copied path of the script in an another file callcommands.

path to script/Appendkeys

path to script/Client

path to script/Config

path to script/DELKEY

root@xxyy:Path to redis# ./redis-cli < path to script/callcommands

(error) ERR unknown command 'path to script/AppendKeys'

(error) ERR unknown command 'path to script/Client'
.....

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: looks like this is a command shell script. correct? what does redis have to do with this?

Comment: I need to run all redis commands and so I am putting them in a scripts, but I can only call one script at a time../redis-cli < path to script/APPENDCOMAND. I want to copy all the scripts in a scripts and run all commands at one time rather then one by one

Comment: I think if you create a Lua script with all the commands then you can run it as a single command.

Comment: I already have different scripts for combination of commands,so it will hard to change all of then in one Lua script. Is there any other way ?

Comment: could you explain what the problem is precisely? in the post you say that you are getting command shell errors, and in the comments you are saying that you want to run all of them in a single command. this is confusing.

Comment: I want to run all of them in a single command. Error that I posted when I am calling a scripts with in another script. That is what exactly I want to do

Comment: you cannot load external libraries into your Lua script. you can combine all your scripts into a single string and send this string to `EVAL`.